# display eldoc help info behind point

Tags: overlays, doc-strings, eldoc

I have the following code to replace default eldoc display function:

```lisp
(defun my-eldoc-display-message-momentary (format-string &rest args)
    "Display eldoc message near point."
    (when format-string
      ;; (pos-tip-show (apply 'format format-string args))
      (momentary-string-display
       (apply 'format format-string args)
       (save-excursion (forward-line) (point))
       )
      ))

(setq eldoc-message-function #'my-eldoc-display-message-momentary)
```

But it does not work smoothly.

- it display slowly
- the exit-char for `momentary-string-display` should be excepted in most
  programming code inputting (not SPC, not [a-zA-Z], not [*,-+=!] etc)

Hope someone can improve it.

Comment: Would you mind to define the slowness?  I've tested the code above but didn't see the slowness, meaning that `pos-tip-show` version and `momentary-string-display` version displays in the same timing on my system, as far as I can tell.  Would you also tell me about excepted `exit-char`?  What behavior are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with the comment, `pos-tip-show` works fine for me too.

I did hack together a better (but not perfect) version of the `momentary-string-display` version. I just rewrote the display function so that it deleted the overlay passively through a hook instead of waiting for an exit-char, which doesn't seem appropriate for what you are trying to do. The display function I put together temporarily overwrites the next line of the buffer with the message. See if you like it.

```el
(defvar my-display-overlay nil)

(defun my-delete-string-display ()
  (when (overlayp my-display-overlay)
    (delete-overlay my-display-overlay))
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-delete-string-display))

(defun my-string-display-next-line (string)
  "Overwrite contents of next line with STRING until next command."
  (let ((str (concat
               (make-string (1+ (current-indentation)) 32)
               (propertize (copy-sequence string) 'face '(:background "#3e4451" :extend t))))
         (start-pos nil)
         (end-pos nil))
    (unwind-protect
      (save-excursion
        (my-delete-string-display)
        (forward-line)
        (setq start-pos (point))
        (end-of-line)
        (setq end-pos (point))
        (setq my-display-overlay (make-overlay start-pos end-pos))
        ;; Hide full line
        (overlay-put my-display-overlay 'display "")
        ;; Display message
        (overlay-put my-display-overlay 'before-string str))
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-delete-string-display))))

(defun my-eldoc-display-message-momentary (format-string &rest args)
  "Display eldoc message near point."
  (when format-string
    (my-string-display-next-line (apply 'format format-string args))))

(setq eldoc-message-function #'my-eldoc-display-message-momentary)
```

Comment: Can you add a face for this overlay? So it can has different background color with 'default face. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I added a line to the display function to set a face.

Comment: I added your added line code, but it does not work. And I use your code to created a minor mode https://github.com/stardiviner/eldoc-overlay-mode

Comment: Did you change the face? I set it to default but you'll have to change it to see a difference.

Comment: Yes, I changed face. I also define a face for it. Check out my upper link repo's `develop` branch.

Comment: Can't check now but it's probably eldoc's face overriding your setting. You can try applying your face to the string using propertize or changing the eldoc face directly.

Comment: How to using propertieze at here? I tried to use `customize-face` command to find eldoc faces, but only found one face `eldoc-highlight-function-argument`.

Comment: See the latest edit. This seems to work for me.

Comment: (there's a missing parenthesis before str)

Comment: Fixed the syntax, it should work now.